# Allow private key file

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to build release APK file with Android Studio. Got error regarding existing private key file. Yes, I have added private key file, but I'm OK with it in my current release. How to allow include private key file in application Release version. In case I build as Debug it doesn't complains about that.

Error:

````
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors.
To create a baseline, run `gradlew updateLintBaseline` after adding the following to the module's build.gradle file:
```
android {
    lint {
        baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
    }
}
```
For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot

C:\projects\xxx\app\src\main\res\raw\clientkey.pem: Error: The raw\clientkey.pem file seems to be a private key file. Please make sure not to embed this in your APK file. [PackagedPrivateKey]

   Explanation for issues of type "PackagedPrivateKey":
   In general, you should not package private key files inside your app.

   https://goo.gle/PackagedPrivateKey

1 errors, 0 warnings
````

Comment: Did changing the lint configuration resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are aware [hardcoded secrets can easily be exposed by reverse-engineering your app](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/risks/hardcoded-cryptographic-secrets?source=studio). So your private key will no longer be private when you publish your app like this.

**Disclaimer**: For a regular use-case, the following solution is not the way to go. Use the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/keystore) to store keys instead.

If you want to ignore this warning, try to add the following to the module's [`build.gradle`](https://developer.android.com/build#module-level) file:

```
android {
    ...
    lint {
        // Turns off checks for the issue IDs you specify.
        disable += "PackagedPrivateKey"
    }
}
```

For more linting configuration options, see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#gradle).